# Replace a c# wcf service with C++/CLI Service

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, c++-cli

I am writing a wcf service in c++/cli to replace a WCF service in c#. However, when I try to use the client which is using the c# reference(required for minimum modification to client), some calls won't happend and some function when called doesnot have data in the parameter at server side.
I tried to change the binding type to see if it works in any other binding but It doesnot work.

So,My question is if this is feasible or not? if not why?

Comment: My comment may be off topic but... is there any actual reason to replace your c# service with one in c++/cli?

Comment: because we have a some code in native c++ whuch we want to hook up with c++/cli server to listen to same contracts and interface

Comment: You'd prefer to interop from c# with native c++.

Comment: I would write the bulk of the code for the service in C#, and call in to a C++/CLI assembly when necessary, e.g., to handle that one message that needs to be processed by C++. C++/CLI is for interop, not for developing your entire application.

Comment: It is used more or less only for interop. A C# application code creates the WCF service. C++/CLI is used to write the contracts and callbacks which loads and calls function from native DLL.

Answer (score 0):

I also created a WCF service to use a existing native C++ code library.

I found that it is simpler, to do it the C# way.

So I have a functional interface defined in C# or C++/CLI.

I write and create the WCF interface using C#. The C# object creates an object in an C++/CLI module/assembly that exposes the interface mentioned before. So my C# WCF services directly calls the C++/CLI assembly.

Finally my C++/CLI code calls and uses the native library.

It is possible to do it without the interface but I found it more convenient for my case.

Comment: In my case, the C# service interface was already there and C# client was using the C# service throught the same contracts in the DLL. Now, I want to leave the Client as it using the old DLL and I have written a C++/CLI DLL with contracts and server interface. So, this doesn't seem to work correctly although WCF is IPC